# Migrating to Django 1.4

Tags: django, migration, django-1.4

I'm currently developing a website in Django v1.2.7. That's the version as per requirements, but I think I could change it without problems. I was thinking about using v1.3 (because of class-based views, etc), but the version 1.4 was released a few weeks ago. My questions are:

- **Does it worth migrating to Django 1.4?**
- **What incompatibilities could I face when updating the version?**

Comment: I have just upgraded to Django 1.4 (but from 1.3 in my case). I found multiple incompatibilities with other packages (South, Haystack, Django-extensions, ...) but all of them where easily solved by just upgrading those packages to their latest versions. I used virtualenv to separate the 1.4 dev environment from the 1.3.

Answer (score 12):

Both your questions are answered at the [release page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/) for 1.4